# Jquery UI Tab force content + tab to specified height

Tags: jquery-ui

Using Jquery UI's tabs I want to be able to set the tab + tab content views together to be a specific height say 500px. Since the height of the tab section varies by theme and I cannot know what height to use in px for the content view so I cannot hard code it. How do you force the whole thing to a specific height?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the entire block inside a `div` and apply `max-height` CSS property to it.